# How to extract jquery ajax data to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am struggling to understand why it is not working. My .json file is correct but I cannot extract the data to display them on Html.

weather.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "weather.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json", // Returns JSON
        success: function(response) {
            var sTxt = '';
            $.each(response.weather, function(index) {
                sTxt += '<tr><td>' + response.weather[index].name + '</td></tr>';
            });
            $('#weatherlist').append(sTxt);
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

weather.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax and json Data</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="weather.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>British and Irish Counties - Weather Data</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <table id="weatherlist">
        </table>
        <div id="updatemessage"></div>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the new Html, with the  before the existing one, I still have an error: jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/jull/Desktop/weather.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax and json Data</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="weather.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>British and Irish Counties - Weather Data</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <table id="weatherlist">
        </table>
        <div id="updatemessage"></div>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post response coming from AJAX? first check is it valid json or not using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: try `JSON.parse(response)` in success callback

Comment: Are you getting an error message in the console?

Comment: From your HTML source, there is nothing to be retrieved!

Comment: "My .json file is correct" — What does it look like?

Comment: "but I cannot extract the data" — Where does it fail? Does the success function even fire? Why don't you have an error function?

Answer (score 4):

Open your browser's Developer Tools. Look in the Console. It will say:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

You are trying to use jQuery, but you haven't included it.

Add another script element (before the one you have already) and use it to load [the jQuery library](http://jquery.com/download/).

Comment: After adding the script to jquery library, nothing is happening...How i am supposed to include it with.load() ?

Comment: `load` is a jQuery function (so you can't use it without first loading jQuery) used to load HTML content (not scripts) into elements in the current page … so no. You include jQuery with `<script src="etc">` (as I said at the start of the last sentence of the answer).

Comment: Yes included it on my .html with the <script> tag (hosted online) and I have the same error.

Comment: @Jullian-lucBarber — **before** I said **before**

Answer (score 1):

```
You have to use 

JSON.parse(response)
```

Comment: If so, then something is really rather wong with the server (and there is no evidence that that is the case in the question). The OP has said `dataType: "json"` so whatever content-type the server returns, jQuery will ignore it and parse the response as JSON **before** passing the result to the success function.